# Python Turtle module game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game using the turtle module in python, how do I move images I've drawn? I'm making an unfair randomness game and I need to edit and move 'cells' or board pieces.

I've tried to move it using a basic 'move' function, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you also include your code for more context?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't know what to do and I don't know how to start this. I've got code that right now makes a chessboard. It's also got some other stuff. I use replit, so here's the link: https://replit.com/@MarsDarklighter/Turtle-Graphics#main.py

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I know of is to turn of screen refreshing and redraw the image when you have to move it. For example:

```
import turtle as t
import time

t.tracer(False)
t.hideturtle()

def MyShape(x, y):
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.clear()
    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(30)
        t.left(90)
    t.update()

def event():
    MyShape(20, 20)

MyShape(0, 0)
time.sleep(1)

MyShape(10, 10)


t.mainloop()
```

This will draw a square at (0, 0), wait one second, and move it to (10, 10)